# Splitting a scala class while preserving thisful access

Tags: scala

I split a large class into a class and a trait that mixes into the class.  What are my options for accessing members of the class from the trait?

A simplified depiction of the task at hand:

```
class A extends B {
  def someA = 3
}

trait B {
  def someB = someA + 3 
}
```

Currently I require an object of type A as an argument in each member function of B, unlike shown above, which of course works, like so:

```
trait B {
  def someB(a: A) = a.someA + 3 // not found: value SomeA
}
```

Could be nice having something like the code above that works, or a `this` or `self` of a sort to use in the trait.

Motivation being less changes when moving methods around between the class and traits, and code looking quite the same in both locations. One way I know of is a self-type. Anything else?

Comment: If `B` requires so much from `A`, I'd argue they aren't really split.

Comment: And you are right, but it is better than one huge class source file. And sometimes, it's not that B requires anything from A, other than being able to apply its methods to an object of type A with plain . notation.

Comment: Not if you have to resort to tricks for the code to still work.  If you can't identity and separate specific concerns, you probably shouldn't separate the code.

Comment: See my previous comment, it is often just for using . notation over instances of type A. By the way this kind of splitting is common using the cake pattern and it's variants.

Comment: But again, why are they separated physically if they can't be separated logically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to use self type, as you have mentioned:

```
class A extends B {
  def someA = 3
}

trait B {
  this: A =>
  def someB = someA + 3
}
```

The other is to have `someA` as an abstract method in `B`, and have `A` provide the concrete implementation for it:

```
class A extends B {
  def someA = 3
}

trait B {
  def someA: Int
  def someB = someA + 3
}
```

Or alternatively have this method defined higher in the subtype hierarchy, which is useful if several traits `A` depends on have to use `someA`

```
class A extends B {
  def someA = 3
}

trait B extends C {
  def someB = someA + 3
}

trait C {
  def someA: Int
}
```